# TraceInputStream missing on SpringBootApp

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

EmailService

```
@Service
public class EmailService {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender sender;

    public void send() throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

        helper.setText("Test body");
        helper.setSubject("Test subject");
        helper.setTo("mail@gmail.com");
        sender.send(message);
    }
}
```

Inside `target/project/WEB-INF/lib` I got both:

`javax.mail-1.5.3.jar` and `spring-boot-starter-mail-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar`,
yet I got

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.(Ljava/io/InputStream;Lcom/sun/mail/util/MailLogger;)V

edit:
I'v checked with `dependency:tree`, few other dependencies needed to exclude older version of `mailapi`. Right now the only mail related dependency I got is `spring-boot-starter-mail` which includes `java-mail 1.5.5`, but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Remove your `javax.mail` dependency that interferes with the dependencies from `spring-boot-starter-mail`. Also make sure you aren't mixing versions of Spring Boot jars (you generally want to avoid defining the `<version>` in a Spring Boot application due the either the `<parent>` or a `<dependencyManagement>` section in your `pom.xml`).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems related to the missing jar in classpath. To be sure that TraceInputStream is loaded try to add the below code in any class method and debug :

```
URL path = this.getClass().getResource("com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream");
System.out.println(path.getFile());
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The error is `NoSuchMethodError`, not `ClassNotFoundException`.

Please check the output of the

```
System.out.println(
   TraceInputStream.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

It could mostly point to an older version of the library.